# MongoDb - How to create a valid JSON/Javascriipt object with ObjectId("") as value?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The following is a valid MongoDb query:

```
  db.persons.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "$or": [{
            "$expr": {
                "$eq": ["$_id", ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")]
            }
        }]
    }

}])
```

However the problem here is that I can not create a valid JavaScript object that looks like:

```
 [{
    "$match": {
        "$or": [{
            "$expr": {
                "$eq": ["$_id",  ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96") ]
            }
        }]
    }
}
}]
```

Because `ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96"` is neither a string nor a number.
I need to have a valid javascript object because I want to store it somewhere and fetch it on the fly and execute, how do I do it?

**EDIT:**
I tried the following in node:

```
 var   mquery=[
            {
              "$match": {
                "$or": [
                  {
                    "$expr": {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$_id",
                        {
                          "$oid": "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ];
          const result = await this.db.collection("persons").aggregate(mquery).toArray();
```

and got :
`MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$oid'`

Comment: Can't you just store object id (5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96) in your case, and then generate rest of the query on the fly?

Comment: Does ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96") have some kind of toString method

Comment: First that specific query could be a simple: db.persons.find({_id: ObjectId('5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96')}) . Second, do you need to store it as JSON? Cause you could use BSON to serialize the query object; or you need to specify your own JSON encoder that serializes ObjectId('123') -> { $oid: '123' }

Comment: I am writing a simple query builder.  The mongo db query is generated on the fly. The question is how do you create the query pragmatically? 
I mean  I could write `{
                "$eq": ["$phone",   "342355" ]
            }`
with no problems but I can't write `{
                "$eq": ["$_id",  ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96") ]
            }`

Comment: the query could have been with find() but then this is a simplistic version of what I actually need. So I do need aggregate

Comment: @Magiczne that is the question. How? How do I generate it on the fly? I need to generate the mongodb query and store it in a variable. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/), convert string id to object id,

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", { "$toObjectId": "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96" }] } }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8j_SXkdXLzx)

Comment: Could you please modify this : `db.persons.aggregate([{
 "$match": {
  "$or": [{
   "$expr": {
    "$eq": ["$_id", ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")]
   }
  }]
 }

}])` to make it work?

Comment: `"$eq": [ {"$oid":"5d505646cf6d4fe581014ab2"}]` this wouldnt work

Comment: strange I got ` unrecognized $oid .` when i executed in shell. I did not try with node yet

Comment: same with node.. let me add what i did in question itself.

Comment: updated answer, i don't know why its not working, but $oid is type of object id, might be that is the reason we can not use directly type

Comment: So there is no consistent way to query keys that are ObjectId and those that are not? 
If I am filtering based on a key that happens to be ObjectId, I need do :
`[ "$_id", { "$toObjectId": "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96" } ]`

But if it is not ObjectId then I have to do : ``"$eq": [ "$phone", "23138213" ]``

Comment: this is the consistent way to use `$toObjectId` to convert string to object id, for your example you can do.

Comment: i was wrong first time because mongob is using `$oid` internally to convert to identify object id, might be we can not use that in query part.

Comment: I get that but what I am asking is that if I were filtering on PhoneNo I would have to do :
`[ "$phone", "23138213" ]` but if I have to filter using any property that is ObjectID I would have to do 
`["$_id", { "$toObjectId": "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96" }]` this means I have to be aware before hand that the property I am querying on is ObjectId. In RDBS user doesnt need to know if the column in WHERE clause is primary key or not

Comment: yes that is why because mongodb (NoSQL) works in json based structure without identification it will not recognize what is the type of field value and and in RDBMS its already relational and stored references for the field, you can check more differences this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained/nosql-vs-sql)

Comment: in sort [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d8/c8/83/d8c883032c19b364db5b719cb6f3fe1d.jpg) and [this](https://data2.polantis.com/image1000/data/732/29026/Red%20Lamborghini%20Huracan%20Car%2092_3D_p.png) both having own ability to work, but if you think [this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQGJK1vq4Jke9PIpzzFYLkXdBPkO-hb6TVANw&usqp=CAU) and [this](https://www.mantaworld.com/img/gallery/custom-cars/wheelsday2005/thumbs/images/DSCF0131_jpg.jpg) its not possible and difficult to use original features in different environment

Comment: The problem is that I am in need of a consistent way of of querying. If what you said is true then in that case in my query builder I am going to have to do something like:

 `if(item.Property.startsWith("_")){                    
                    cond["$expr"][item.operator].push({ "$toObjectId": item.operatorValue})
                }else{
                    cond["$expr"][item.operator].push(...item.operatorValue)
                }`

Comment: I am not sure with this `if(item.Property.startsWith("_")){`, because it is possible other fields, like reference ids also have ObjectID then this will fail. i don't know your schemas and structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [js-bson](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson#node-no-bundling). The ObjectId type is [defined here](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/objectid.js). Try:

```
const BSON = require('bson');

let oid = new BSON.ObjectId("cafecafecafecafecafecafe")
```

Then use the $eq operator instead of  $expr with $eq.